# How can we retrive the metrices 'annotationClickableImpressions' and 'annotationClosableImpressions' using yt gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have to integrate you youtube API in my rails application. I am using 'yt' gem to pull the youtbe analytics of videos. However I could not find ay endpoint to pull  the 'annotationClickableImpressions' and 'annotationClosableImpressions' through the yt' gem.
Is there any method or endpoint available to pull the above mentioned metrices.
If not, How cna I be able to pull the endpoints directly through the Youtube API in my rails app. Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client.execute!(:api_method => youtube_analytics.reports.query, :parameters => {
:ids => 'channel==own_channel_id', 
'end-date' => '2014-02-15', 
'start-date' => '2014-02-01', 
:metrics => 'views'
})
```

Other metrics that can be use [list of metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#Core_Metrics).

But I think you should be reminded of some details about Anotation Metrics

## Annotations metrics

[*annotationClickThroughRate (core metric)*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#Annotations_Metrics)

> The ratio of annotations that viewers clicked to the total number of clickable annotation impressions. This is a core metric and is subject to the *Deprecation Policy*.

[*annotationCloseRate (core metric)*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#Annotations_Metrics)

> The ratio of annotations that viewers closed to the total number of annotation impressions. This is a core metric and is subject to the *Deprecation Policy*.

## Deprication

> Google will announce if it intends to discontinue or make backwards incompatible changes to this API or Service. Google will use commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate those YouTube API versions and features identified at http://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list without these changes until the later of: (i) one year after the announcement or (ii) April 20, 2015, unless (as Google determines in its reasonable good faith judgment):
>
> - required by law or third party relationship (including if there is a change in applicable law or relationship), or
> - doing so could create a security risk or substantial economic or material technical burden.
>
> The above policy is the "Deprecation Policy."

## NOTE:

> YouTube Analytics API reports only return data for the annotationClickThroughRate and annotationCloseRate metrics as of June 10, 2012. In addition, YouTube Analytics API reports only return data for the remaining annotation metrics as of July 16, 2013.